# Image Display by Pushbutton

Tags: qt

I am using the Qtdesigner and I am new to it so my question is i have a Q-pushbutton & that is created with the help of the Qtdesigner i want to add a image to it by adding a label widget to it which will be in the same frame " that is if i press the Q-pushbutton it should display the image on that label widget which would be in the same frame, so I tried to do it in the editing style sheet by adding this code to the edit style sheet of the frame as this

```
QPushButton:pressed{class = Qlabel}
label_92 {image: url(:/i_Diagram/i_diagram/idiagram3.png);}
```

but this wont work so can some one help with this

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with stylesheets? You can connect the `clicked` signal of the `QPushButton` to a slot where you set the image for your label. Or just hide the label and show it when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an image to a QPushButton in Qt Creator, you can set it in the properties, after selecting the button:-

[image: Set Icon Properties]

Note the icon here, which has previously been added to a Qt resource file, then chosen here in the properties. You can add text too.

If you still want to set an image on a separate label, then you can do this in code, assuming your dialog was created with a matching class (Qt Designer Form Class). Supposing you named your PushButton 'SetImagePushButton', in its matching class you can add a slot

```
void on_SetImagePushButton_clicked();
```

Note how the name of the button matches the name of the slot, followed by its signal. Then, in the implementation, simply set the label's image:-

```
void on_SetImagePushButton_clicked()
{
     ui-> label_92->setPixmap(":\i_diagram\idiagram3.png"); // image placed in a Qt resource
}
```

Done correctly, Qt will handle the connection of the button to its slot.

Comment: The syntax for connecting signals to slots by name is [`void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName).

Comment: @thuga, Oops of-course it is. Thanks for noticing ;O)

Comment: I'd also recommend using `clicked` signal instead of `released` :)

Comment: @thuga I suppose so, if shortcuts and animateClick is to be caught too.